# In Corda, how can I check whether an RPC connection is broken and automatically reconnect?

Tags: corda

I have an RPC connection to my Corda node, which I use to start flows and query the vault.

Is there a recommended approach for checking if the connection dies and automatically reconnecting?

Answer (score 1):

As of Corda 4, there is no built-in API to detect disconnects or automatically reconnect when a disconnect occurs.

However, these `RpcReconnectTests` define a `ReconnectingRPCConnection` class that wraps a regular `CordaRPCConnection` and automatically reconnects to the node when the connection breaks: [RpcReconnectTests](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/ca4e1c5e34719d34b4178f04acb3a6b1b86bcc6f/node/src/integration-test/kotlin/net/corda/node/services/rpc/RpcReconnectTests.kt).

In particular, take a look at `Test that the RPC client is able to reconnect and proceed after node failure, restart, or connection reset`, which shows how to use `ReconnectingRPCConnection` to handle connection breaks when doing things such as starting flows and observing the vault.